# Operator Integrals in Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the Alhors' proof of the Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem and I do not know how to prove that if $\alpha \neq 0$, than, for $1 < q <2$, the function below is an element of $L^{q}$ (in the Lebesgue complex measure space):
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z - \alpha)}$$
Does somebody know how can I do it?

Comment: It isn't. Are you missing some sort of square-root in your expression? Like: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x-1))}}\in L^q$ for those $q$, but $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$ isn't, since it's not integrable at $0$.

Comment: When you say $L^q$, what measure space are you referring to?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I don't know what "integrable at $0$" means, but in fact the function $1/z(z-1)$ is integrable on any compact subset of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Since we talk about  Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem, these are complex (area) integrals on bounded domains and then obviously $\frac{1}{|z^q|}dA$ ~$r^{1-q}drd\theta$ near zero so the function is integrable there if $q-1 <1$ so indeed if $1<q<2$ and since same applies at $\alpha \ne 0$ the result is true

Comment: Right... we're in two dimensions.

Comment: Thank you guys! It finally worked! I used @Conrad argument!

Comment: @excellent and happy to be of help!